# Android Studio is unable to find ADB, yet I'm able to deploy to my device

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, adb

[image]

The exact error I'm getting is "`java.lang.Throwable: ADB not found`"

I haven't found anything online matching my problems. I have already (manually) reinstalled the platform tools multiple times. And they work. I can connect to my phone, even Android Studio is able to run the project on my phone. Yet it throws that error and locks some of the features like Logcat (I can use Logcat via the shell just fine). I've also tested Android Studio 3.3 additionally, but it didn't change anything.

The google USB driver is installed too.

Comment: I know it says "configure Android SDK" but I can't find anything broken. I have 2 SDK versions, the build tools, the platform tools and the SDK tools installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I opened Android Studio today, it randomly worked.

The whole "whole App chrashing on startup"-thing was a bug I introduced.

Answer (score 1):

The ADB tool is originally installed on `.../android-sdk/platform-tools/platform-tools/` and Android Studio doesn't recognise the tool inside this location. After tried all the other suggestions, the only solution that worked for me was to copy the `adb` file from this folder to the parent folder: `.../android-sdk/platform-tools/`. It worked like a charm.

Some particularities of my system:

- OS: macOS Catalina
- IDE: IntelliJ IDEA CE (the same occurred when I tried to work with Android Studio)
- SKD installation method: installed trough Homebrew with the cask android-sdk (the same occurred when I tried to install from within Android Studio)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you installed adb drivers externally and not via Android Studio and hence they are not present inside the platform tools of the Android SDK. I would recommend installing it using Android Studio's inbuilt SDK Manager.

**Steps**

1. Open SDK Manager in Android Studio (you can find it at top right
   with android logo and downward arrow and also in the Tools Menu at
   the top).
2. In SDK Manager click on **SDK Tools** tab and checkmark the
   **Android SDK Platform Tools**
3. Apply changes and your issue should be resolved.

I hope this helps.

I am attaching a Screenshot for your reference:-

[image: SDK Tools Tab]

Comment: Thank you for your time, but I installed them that way in the first place. I also tried reinstalling them manually and via the SDK tools manager, didn't help either.

Comment: Just read your other answer glad to know you solved your problem. Happy Coding!